# Handle Dynamic import failure in vue

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, import

I have to import some custom components that should override standard ones. 
Those custom components are loaded with an environment variable to selected custom folder that contain those client's custom component.
A custom component should not exist, so i can't be able to find a way to catch dynamic import failure.

I need to handle this situation:

```
const component = () => import('path_custom_not_existent..):
if(!component) {
component = () => import('path_standard_sure')
}
```

So i can't override all the components for each clients, but only what I need.

I tried with try/catch, but it doesn't work.
I tried import(...).then().catch() but it still not working.
Everytime I use "import" with wrong path, it shows me 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve...'

I'm using this composer.json (vue-cli standard...)

```
{
  "name": "shockdom.front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-focus": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.7",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a promise off of it:

```
const component = () => import('path_custom_not_existent..)
  .then((m) => m.default)
  .catch(err) => import ('404_component_does_not_exist)
```

Comment: And you're using [https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/)? You can see that [webpack uses this method as well](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports). So as long as you have that babel-preset available, you can use this method.

Comment: Did you solve your problem I'm also looking for something like this